# Samza task is taking more space even though no process is being performed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, out-of-memory, heap-memory, apache-samza

I am having microservices run in Samza containers connected using Kafka messaging streams. In a few tasks, memory being used is constantly increasing even though no process is being performed. Not sure why is this happening and sometimes the container is failing because of a lack of space issues. Does anyone know why is this happening and how to get it fixed?